# how to get value from datasource using display name?

Tags: c#, xpath, infopath2010

lets say I have a data source:

```
    <Things>
        <thing display = "Choose..." value = "-1"/>
        <thing display = "Car" value = "01"/>
        <thing display = "Book" value = "47"/>
        <thing display = "Plane" value = "20"/>
        <thing display = "Other" value = "1"/>
    </Things>
```

And I need to define a value for Car, for example, by Using display name "car".
So, if I used "Car", I should be able to define that its value=01.

```
XPathNavigator nav = DataSources["MyXmlData"].CreateNavigator();
nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("/Things/thing[./display='Car']");
nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("./value");
```

what is a righr way? What wrong I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use function: [lower-case](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-lower-case)

working xPath example:

```
/Things/thing[lower-case(@display)='car']/@value
```

Comment: XPathException was unhandled. Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that in single line :

```
nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("/Things/thing[@display='Car']/@value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute expression is wrong in your xpath query.

---

Xpath Expression ([For More](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp))

/      Selects from the root node

.      Selects the current node

@      Selects attributes

---

If you want to select a single node by attribute

```
var selectedNode= xpathNavigator.SelectSingleNode("/Things/thing[@display='Car']");
```

if you want to get a attribute value from selected node

```
var value = result.GetAttribute("value", string.Empty);
```